# Which is more user friendly: TortoiseGit or TortoiseHG?

Tags: version-control, tortoisehg, tortoisegit, git-extensions

I have been experimenting with using Mercurial and TortoiseHG to track my work when I am working remotely (with a slow VPN I don't want to commit to SVN unless I have something that works).
I have found TortoiseHG a bit hard to use - or at least it often doesn't work the way I expect it to, so I am considering switching to GIT and TortoiseGIT.
(For example I had problems rolling back source code to an earlier version and I still don't know what I did wrong)

My question whether they have a similar level of functionality / user friendliness or whether one is better than the other. What has your experience been?

Update for those interested in the topic:
My company has moved to git and we are using [GitExtensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) instead of Tortoise.
I am really happy with it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931105/tortoisegit-tortoisebzr-tortoisehg-are-any-solid-enough-to-switch-from-tortois ?

Comment: Thanks for the link, summary: 2 votes for TortoiseHG, one for TortoiseGIT

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550091/best-support-now-on-windows-mercurial-or-git/

Comment: Isn't the question really, should you use Mercurial or Git?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using TortoiseHg 1.1.7.  I switched to the newest version a while back, and quickly switched back because I didn't like the interface.  If you don't like what you have now, then it's worth trying other options (what you like will be highly dependent on what other interfaces you're familiar with), but I recommend that you include an old version of TortoiseHg in your list of things to try.  Hg does have better Windows compatibility than Git.